# Livewires + Pygame Error

Tags: python, pygame, importerror, livewires

So I am running Windows 8 with python 3.3 installed. I have livewires and pygame installed.

But when I run the code:

```
from livewires import games

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

games.screen.mainloop()
```

I get an error saying... ImportError: No module name 'pygame.image'.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what is the filename of your script?

Comment: The filename of the script is new_graphics_window.py.

Comment: do you have a pygame.py script in the same directory? Can you import just pygame? How about pygame.locals?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pygame in the file directory of the python interpreter? But anyway pygame is not available for python 3.3 at the moment. If you want to use python 3 for coding, I would recommend 3.1.1 or 3.2, and use python 2.7.12 to compile them into an .exe file with pyinstaller, because pip is not compatible with 3.1.1 and 3.2. You can also write the code in python 2. I would recommend 2.7.12

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [README.md file](https://github.com/livewires/python/blob/master/module/README.md) in the distro's module directory, you'll see that it was committed on September 25, 2013 and specifically states:

> You will need Python to use the package. Python can be obtained from: http://www.python.org/download/. If you're installing for the first time, we recommend you use Python 2.2.3

I think it's quite likely that livewires will not work with Python 3.