# 'Python Programming for the absolute beginner' - livewires

Tags: python, livewires

I want to put a stop to this damn problem once and for all. In the 'Python Programming for the absolute beginner' book, it asks you to download its special version of livewires and pygame along with python 3.1.1. However, using the code

```
from livewires import games
input("Press enter . . .")
```

I get this error when ran.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Python31\TEST", line 1, in , <module>
          from livewires import games, colors
       File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 57, in <module>
          import pygame, pygame.image, pygame.nixer, pygame.font, pygame.transform
    ImportError: No module named 'pygame.image'
```

I've been trying to solve this for ages! Something i noticed is the line:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 57, in <module>
```

and how it says 'Python34' not 'Python31' like the first line with a path. Is it going to the wrong place? What is wrong with my damn python? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Damn Python problems. This question has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802629/python-livewires-console-error) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418328/livewires-pygame-error) as well.

Comment: Yeah, its damn annoying

Comment: At least 4 hours i've sunk into this

Comment: The question has been asked, but there is no answer in the linked-to question; though the chat log shows that *that* problem was solved.

Comment: @Lixerman99, well spotted. You clearly have two versions of python on your system, 3.1 and 3.4. If you're just starting out, that's one too many. I have no experience with _this_ software (livewires/pygame), but I suggest you delete the `C:\Python31` and repeat the installation process so everything ends in the same place. (Or vice versa if it's incompatible with version 3.4, but the other question thread suggests that it isn't.)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I can finally start making terrible games!